# how to Retrieve time bound follower statistics broken by Demographic Facets in Linkedin page management api?

Tags: linkedin-api

I am using `organizationalEntityFollowerStatistics` API given on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/follower-statistics?tabs=http). When I use time interval lifetime I am getting follower count by 7 Demographic Facets but when I use time intervals I am only getting follower increase decrease data.
How to get day-wise data broken by Demographic Facets in LinkedIn API?

My day-wise data call URL `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityFollowerStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=${urn}&timeIntervals=(timeRange:(start:1634197752000,end:1636876152000),timeGranularityType:DAY)`

Answer (score 0):

`Time-bound follower counts are aggregated and not segmented by facet.`
I found this on their documentation page.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/follower-statistics?tabs=http
First Note on this page.